# Cannot set MX of other server on my domain

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind

in bind, i am trying to set MX servers for my domain, but i get the domainname.com appended to the MX server. i do now know how to avoid it.

here is my entry in MX zone file

```
example.com.    120 IN  MX  10 mx00.1and1.co.uk
example.com.    120 IN  MX  20 mx01.1and1.co.uk
```

But when do a DIG MX of example.com, i get this:

```
example.com.          120     IN      MX      10 mx00.1and1.co.uk.example.com.
example.com.          120     IN      MX      20 mx01.1and1.co.uk.example.com.
```

How to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to put the dot `.` at the end of your FQDN.

Answer (score 1):

In a master zone file, any field that contains a *name* is considered relative to the current origin unless it includes the trailing dot (indicating an absolute name).

[In BIND the origin is set to the zone name by default](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#id2601371) but this can be overridden any number of times using the $ORIGIN directive.

> <domain-name>s make up a large share of the data in the master file.
> The labels in the domain name are expressed as character strings and
> separated by dots.  Quoting conventions allow arbitrary characters to
> be stored in domain names.  Domain names that end in a dot are called
> absolute, and are taken as complete.  Domain names which do not end in
> a dot are called relative; the actual domain name is the concatenation
> of the relative part with an origin specified in a $ORIGIN, $INCLUDE,
> or as an argument to the master file loading routine.  A relative name
> is an error when no origin is available.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#section-5.1